# Isotope items reposition issue after append

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to set up Ajax post loading with Isotope. But I'm having trouble loading in the posts and displaying them in the grid. Loaded grid-items are either added to the top of the grid or are not positioned by Isotope.

**Update**! I've just noticed that on double click grid-items are positioned properly. But why not on the first click?

```
<div id="filters" class="button-group"></div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>
```

**Isotope setup**

```
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
    sortBy : 'random',
itemSelector: '.grid-item',
masonry: {
    columnWidth: 200
    },
sortAscending: {
    name: true,
    number: false,
    date: false,
},
getSortData: {
    name: '.name',
    date: '.date',
    number : '.number',
    category: '[data-category]',
}
});
```

**load-posts.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var pageNum = parseInt(rvidee_alp.startPage) + 1; // The number of the next page to load (/page/x/).    
    var max = parseInt(rvidee_alp.maxPages); // The maximum number of pages the current query can return.
    var nextLink = rvidee_alp.nextLink; // The link of the next page of posts.
    var grid = $('.grid'); // Posts container

    if(pageNum <= max) {
        $('.posts') // Insert the "More Posts" link.
            .append('<div class="col"><a id="load-posts" href="#0">Load more</a></div>');   
        $('.navigation').remove(); // Remove the traditional navigation.
    }

    $(document).on('click', '#load-posts', function(){

        if(pageNum <= max) { // Are there more posts to load?       
            $(this).text('Loading posts...');   
            $.get(nextLink, function(data){ 

                pageNum++;
                nextLink = nextLink.replace(/\/page\/[0-9]?/, '/page/'+ pageNum);           
                $(data).find('.grid-item').appendTo(grid);

                    if(pageNum <= max) {
                        $('#load-posts').text('Load more');
                    } else {
                        $('#load-posts').text('No more to load.');
                    }
            });                         
        } else {
            $('#load-posts').append('.');
        }
        $('.grid').isotope( 'reloadItems').isotope();
        return false;   
    });

});
```

I figured I'd try to get ('.grid-item') data into variable so I could call for it under $(grid) but I couldn't get it to work. Currently posts are added but Isotope is not positioning them.

Just let me know if you need to see the setup in functions.php.

**Update!** I've just noticed that on double click grid-items are positioned properly. But why not on the first click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. Instead of *append* and *reloadItems*, I should have used *insert* from the beginning. Needed to change 2 lines:

```
var newItems = $(data).find('.grid-item');
$('.grid').isotope( 'insert', newItems );
```